# How to create search bar look like google play

Tags: android, uisearchbar

I'm developing an application with contain a search bar like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rwvr.jpg]

I attempted to insert "search icon" and "clear text icon" inside the autocompleteView and made it clickable but unsuccessfully!
I'm looking forward to receive your support and attention. all will be appreciated.

Comment: my application targets in android

Answer (score 0):

Use [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html). Read the guid and you will understand what to do.