# Implementing Google play and maps like Search Bar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-toolbar, android-search

I have a requirement to create a Google play and maps like search bar with filter in my project, but I have no idea how to start with. I tried it by own custom implementation like as follows:

**Autocomplete TextView inside ToolBar android**

**MainActivity.java**

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar (toolbar);

        ArrayList<String> searchArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        searchArrayList.add("United States");
        searchArrayList.add("France");
        searchArrayList.add("United Kingdom");
        searchArrayList.add("India");
        searchArrayList.add("Indonesia");
        searchArrayList.add("Germany");
        searchArrayList.add("Spain");

        AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_item, R.id.textView1, searchArrayList);

        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoComplete);
        autoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**Custom AutoCompleteAdapter class implementation using ArrayAdapter**

AutoCompleteAdapter.java

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements
        Filterable {

    private ArrayList<String> fullList;
    private ArrayList<String> mOriginalValues;
    private ArrayFilter mFilter;

    public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int resource,
                               int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> fullList) {

        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, fullList);
        this.fullList = fullList;
        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fullList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return fullList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (mFilter == null) {
            mFilter = new ArrayFilter();
        }
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ArrayFilter extends Filter {
        private Object lock;

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<String>(fullList);
                }
            }

            if (prefix == null || prefix.length() == 0) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(
                            mOriginalValues);
                    results.values = list;
                    results.count = list.size();
                }
            } else {
                final String prefixString = prefix.toString().toLowerCase();

                ArrayList<String> values = mOriginalValues;
                int count = values.size();

                ArrayList<String> newValues = new ArrayList<String>(count);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String item = values.get(i);
                    if (item.toLowerCase().contains(prefixString)) {
                        newValues.add(item);
                    }

                }

                results.values = newValues;
                results.count = newValues.size();
            }

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

            if (results.values != null) {
                fullList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
            } else {
                fullList = new ArrayList<String>();
            }
            if (results.count > 0) {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that above implementation is not the right way to do it. But what I need to know whether is there any other way or library to accomplish it. I also see that in recent days many of the applications are using similar search bar, kindly please help me with the solutions since no where i can see the exact solutions for these requirement.

In most of the blogs and websites there is only solutions [like](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

Sorry to say this too that most of the StackOverflow posts are also left un answered for the similar questions as follows:

[Implement search bar like in play store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932157/implement-search-bar-like-in-play-store-app)

[How to create search bar look like google play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18847687/how-to-create-search-bar-look-like-google-play)

All your solutions and suggestions are welcome. Kindly please forgive me if my post is not clear and seems unrelevant. Expecting your answers. Thanks in advance